# Doxygen navigation path (breadcrumbs) instructions & group table of content

Tags: doxygen

I'm trying to achieve the same functionality as Qt is having for their documentation with navigation path working same as Windows 7-8 (maybe also vista) i.e. showing whole path from root (module `M`) to component `C` and class `X`. `M->C->X`

Good example:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qnetworksession.html

Must I put some kind of doxygen tags for root and it's child's their subchild's? I checked all the doxygen tags without seeing anything related to navigation path.

I am working with doxygen 1.8.7 which generates navigation path in footer, but everything i click is being displayed as root. Also, how can i put navigation on top of the page/header?

And is it possible to have group table of content displayed? I am having separated model.dox file for each module, which defines new group and contains sections/subsections. Any ideas why table of contents isn't displayed? Everything works well on (main) page using \mainpage \page tag.

Example of my group:

```
/*! \defgroup module1 CommonModule
 *  
 *  \tableofcontents
 *
 *  Module description ..
 *  \section first Init
 */
```

Update 14.7.2014:
Didn't realize Qt documentation is build using qdoc tool, not doxygen so Edit section can be ignored. Questions still remain the same. From what I've experienced it is impossible to group pages and groups together therefor making it impossible to generate module page with list of all classes/namespaces/enums etc. Hopefully I am wrong.

Update 11.9.2014:

- Page can not contain autogenerated list of all classes/namespaces/enums etc.
- Doxygen navigation only shows file path when browsing over file list which isn't that useful since i am mostly browsing the documentation by class/namespace not by file and wish to have file list generation disabled.

Edit:
From checking Qt documentation (source) i see that Qt modules are all doxygen pages and modules page is manually written and not auto generated by doxygen since they probably couldn't get module description with table of content using `\defgroup`. Will do he same if needed. 
Navigation path on the other hand is still a big mystery, they might have used some kind of internal scripting as i see custom tags such as `\nextpage`. It's strange how it's so difficult to find anything related to doxygen navigation on google!